Upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.01 LTS failed - now only command line at 22.04 and no network
Long time Ubuntu user that has gone through many LTS upgrades when the .01 version becomes available.
This time the upgrade has really borked. It looked to try to rollback but clearly has failed.
Now no gui, command line at 22.04, apparently no network (ping 8.8.8.8 does not work).
My (old) laptop does not seem to allow boot from USB (I cut a 24.04.01 iso with Rufus).
So stuck.
It seems my only option is to try to get a 22.04 DVD and see if I can re-install from there unless anyone can suggest a way forward.
TIA

Try Balena Etcher in place of Rufus?

to restore the networking see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1519273/1698042 to restore the desktop, apply sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop or sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

I just had the exact same experience, see my answer here which will hopefully quickly fix your install like it did mine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1525039/1061422

Your message on the other post was deleted, it finally got my networking back and I am getting systems back one at a time as I get through the list of updates that didn't apply.

If you still have the text of the message yourself, then it might be useful to post it as an answer for this question: it is much more directly related.

@GeoffRiley the mods seemed to think my answer was wrong so i'll leave it at that.

Yep that answer has been deleted. Also from another post I have no /etc/resolv.conf.old

Right. I now have network back (you tube vid on how to do and finfing my long network cable!) but still a very borked. system with a seemingly huge number of unmet dependencies. so still looking for a way forward to 24.04 or preferrably back to 22.04

@BarryWinter, what was that video that helped you get networking to work again?
